# How to use ConfigurationManager.AppSettings?

Tags: c#, xml, configuration

In my ASP.NET Application I want to use a path, that I defined in an StartConfig.xml config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <Parameter key="filePath" Value="C:\FilesToWatch"></Parameter>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then I did some research how to use this value in my HomeController and many people say that the ConfigurationManager is the solution so i tried this:

```
string s = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
```

The problem I now have is, that I am not able to use the ConfigurationManager so it is red underlined. Is there something, that I have to import or install?

[image]

Comment: can you show us the build errors?

Comment: @JohnB I added a picture of the error now, but unfortunately it is on german

Comment: @JohnB it sais that I have to add a reference to the Assembly, but I do not really know what that means

Comment: looks like you are missing a ref to `System.Configuratio`...try adding

Comment: @JohnB do I have to add this reference to the whole project folder?

Comment: if you mean project then yes

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the System.Configuration namespace. 
In Solution Explorer, right-click on the References or Dependencies node and choose Add Reference. You can also right-click on the project node and select Add > Reference.

Select the System.Configuration namespace.

[image]

You can now use this namespace in your classes.

```
using System.Configuration;
```